# Why can `%rip + displacement` access data section?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, position-independent-code, relative-addressing

The usage of this is that I saw after used `gcc -S`.

I know `ary` represents the first address of the sequence, then I also know `leaq ary(, %rdi, 4)` has the same effect(assume %rdi equals 0).

But I don't understand, why can `ary(%rip)` access data section. Maybe I lack **the memory layout for program running, or I misunderstand [the addressing modes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GNU_assembly_syntax#Address_operand_syntax)**?

Below is my example.

```
.section .data
ary:
    .int 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

.section .text
.globl  _start

_start:
    leaq ary, %rax
    leaq ary(%rip), %rbx   # ???

    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```